# dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: Invalid item argument on Internet explorer 11

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid

Using `ItemFileReadStore` on Chrome, Safari, Opera or Mozilla works well, however when I try the same source code on Internet Explorer in the developer console writes `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore: Invalid item argument`.

You can find JSON under this line:

```
{"label":"cid","identifier":"cid","items":
[{"cid":"0","cc1":"1111","cc2":"20171216","cc3":"NO TOCAR PRUEBA INFORMATICA","cc4":"<div class='imagepdf'></div>","cc5":"<div><img class='imagok'/></div>"}]}
```

and the message appears when I double clicked on a `datagrid`. Everything works well on every browser except Internet Explorer.

Datagrid structure:

```
tmonitor = new DataGrid({
         id:"restmonitor",
          //style: "width: 100%; height: 15em;",
          escapeHTMLInData: false,
          structure: [
            { name: "Id", field: "cid", width: "5%" },
            { name: "Tubo", field: "cc1", width: "15%" },
            { name: "Fecha", field: "cc2", width: "10%" },
            { name: "Nombre", field: "cc3", width: "50%" },            
            { name: "PDF", field: "cc4", width: "10%" },
            { name: "Estado", field: "cc5", width: "10%" }
          ],
          rowSelector: '20px',
          onRowDblClick: function( evento )
          {
                var idx = evento.rowIndex;
                console.log(idx);
                item = tmonitor.getItem(idx); <---- Hangs here.
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the event. Using dojo/on works right instead using OnRowDblClick.

Thank you